# Applying median filter to data with 2 axes

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I have the following code:

```
x = VarName3;
y = VarName4;
x = (x/6000)/60;
plot(x, y)
```

Where `VarName3` and `VarName4` are `3000x1`. I would like to apply a median filter to this in MATLAB. However, the problem I am having is that, if I use `medfilt1`, then I can only enter a single array of variables as the first argument. And for `medfilt2`, I can only enter a matrix as the first argument. But the data looks very obscured if I convert `x` and `y` into a matrix.

The `x` is time and `y` is a list of integers. I'd like to be able to filter out spikes and dips. How do I go about doing this? I was thinking of just eliminating the erroneous data points by direct manipulation of the data file. But then, I don't really get the effect of a median filter.

Comment: There are 2 filters mentioned in your question. A median filter does not filter out values above and below a range. Which of both do you need?

Comment: But doesn't a median filter help me get rid of spikes in the data?

Comment: Yes, but not the "values higher or lower than a range"

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong wording. What I want is to get rid of outliers. I have edited the OP.

Comment: What is the problem with `medfilt1`? seems like the right option

Comment: It doesn't let me input both x and y. So, I am able to use medfilt1, but then the x-axis is from 1-3000. Instead of the actual x(time) values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using `sort`.

Median is the center element, so you can sort three elements, and take the middle element as median.
`sort` function also returns the index of the previous syntaxes.
I used the index information for restoring the matching value of X.

Here is my code sample:

```
%X - simulates time.
X = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];

%Y - simulates data
Y = [0 1 2 0 100 1 1 1 2 3];

%Create three vectors:
Y0 = [0, Y(1:end-1)]; %Left elements   [0 0 1 2 0 2 1 1 1 2]
Y1 = Y;               %Center elements [0 1 2 0 2 1 1 1 2 3]
Y2 = [Y(2:end), 0];   %Right elements  [1 2 0 2 1 1 1 2 3 0]

%Concatenate Y0, Y1 and Y2.
YYY = [Y0; Y1; Y2];

%Sort YYY:
%sortedYYY(2, :) equals medfilt1(Y)
%I(2, :) equals the index: value 1 for Y0, 2 for Y1 and 3 for Y2.
[sortedYYY, I] = sort(YYY);

%Median is the center of sorted 3 elements.
medY = sortedYYY(2, :);

%Corrected X index of medY
medX = X + I(2, :) - 2;

%Protect X from exceeding original boundries.
medX = min(max(medX, min(X)), max(X));
```

Result:

```
medX =

     1     2     2     3     6     7     7     8     9     9

>> medY

medY =

     0     1     1     2     1     1     1     1     2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sliding window on the data vector centred at a given time. The value of your filtered output at that time is the median value of the data in the sliding window. The size of the sliding window is an odd value, not necessarily fixed to 3.